# function_score for query spanning multiple indices / filter not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I implemented `function_score` successfully for queries running against one index, but have trouble to apply function_score to a query spanning multiple indices with different fields in ElasticSearch 6.2.4.

This query:

```
POST /web_document,web_part/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "type": "best_fields",
                      "query": "sampling probe",
                      "fields": [
                        "titleD.autocomplete^5",
                        "titleE.autocomplete^5"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "_index": {
                        "value": "web_document"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "type": "best_fields",
                      "query": "sampling probe",
                      "fields": [
                        "textD.autocomplete^5",
                        "textE.autocomplete^5"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "_index": {
                        "value": "web_part"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [

        {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": [
                { "exists": { "field": "revDestDate" } },
                { "exists": { "field": "mutationDate" } }
              ]
            }
          },
          "script_score": {
            "script": "100"
          }
        },

        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "_index": "web_part"
            }
          },
          "gauss": {
            "mutationDate": {
              "origin": "now",
              "scale": "90d",
              "decay": 0.5
            }
          },
          "weight": 20
        },

        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "_index": "web_document"
            }
          },
          "gauss": {
            "revDestDate": {
              "origin": "now",
              "scale": "90d",
              "decay": 0.5
            }
          },
          "weight": 20
        }
      ],
      "score_mode" : "first", 
      "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

Returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    …
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "index": "web_document",
        …
        "reason": {
          "type": "parsing_exception",
          "reason": "unknown field [mutationDate]",
          …
        }
      },
      {
        "index": "web_part",
        …
        "reason": {
          "type": "parsing_exception",
          "reason": "unknown field [revDestDate]",
          …
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I also tried to incorporate the function_score in the induvidual query like this,
 which returns the same error:

```
POST /web_document,web_part/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "type": "best_fields",
                      "query": "sampling probe",
                      "fields": [
                        "titleD.autocomplete^5",
                        "titleE.autocomplete^5"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "_index": {
                        "value": "web_document"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "functions": [
              {
                "gauss": {
                  "revDestDate": {
                    "origin": "now",
                    "scale": "90d",
                    "decay": 0.5
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "type": "best_fields",
                      "query": "sampling probe",
                      "fields": [
                        "textD.autocomplete^5",
                        "textE.autocomplete^5"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "_index": {
                        "value": "web_part"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "functions": [
              {
                "gauss": {
                  "mutationDate": {
                    "origin": "now",
                    "scale": "90d",
                    "decay": 0.5
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

According to the comment from Darshan Pratil to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33568620/142679) to the same problem this has worked in past versions.

How can this be done in elastic search 6.2.4?